# Use Shiny to display bar graph by state

Tags: shiny, rstudio

I'm trying to use shiny to create a bar graph for a state that is selected via drop-down box. I'm quite new to R and I've tried a variety of examples to no avail. I have three variables (state, claim #, total $) and for each state there are five values. So something like this:

```
state <- c("PA", "TX", "NY")
claim_num <- c(1:15)
total <- sample(1000:5000, 15)
df <- (state, claim_num, total)
```

I want to have something similar to https://beta.rstudioconnect.com/jjallaire/shiny-embedding/#inline-app but I don't know if I can format my data in that was since I would have a lot of NAs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this (you can download and run the example)?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Sample Shiny App"),       
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         uiOutput("stateInput")
      ),
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("statePlot")
      )
   )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
   state <- sample(state.abb, 3, replace = FALSE)
   total <- sample(1000:5000, 15)
   claimNumber <- 1:15
   data <- data.frame(state, total, claimNumber)

   output$stateInput <- renderUI({
     selectInput(
       inputId = "state",
       label = "Select a State:",
       choices = levels(data$state)
     )
   })

   output$statePlot <- renderPlot({
     hist(data$total[data$state == input$state])
   })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

What we're doing is taking the list of unique states available in our data frame and passing those to our `selectInput` that renders as a dropdown in the UI. From here, we can access whatever value the user has selected through the `input$state` object. More generally, we can access inputs based on whatever we define the `inputId` to be (in this particular case, we call it `state`).

Having grabbed the user input, we can then subset the data frame to only return values that correspond to the user-defined state and, in this case, pass those totals values to a plot that we render as output.